# AddThis alternatives for Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios

AddThis team seems to have abandoned their mobile SDKs completely (the judgement is based on responses from AddThis team on their forum), so the question is - are there any services available (paid is fine) that offer URL sharing service via the compilable and embeddable SDK for Android and iOS?